# Determine velocity coverage in a Python project

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage

Is there a way to determine the % test coverage for new code(as in code added/edited in a new commit) , and fail the tests if it falls below a threshold? This is different from just having a --cov-fail-under attribute in your setup.cfg as this checks your entire codebase and not just new code. The idea is to have 95% code coverage restriction on new code, even though right now our overall code coverage is 40%.

Comment: According to this [blog](https://agostini.tech/2017/07/16/code-coverage-with-codecov/), codecov should be able to do that

Answer (score 1):

[diff-cover](https://pypi.org/project/diff-cover/) can tell you the coverage amount of the lines in your commit.